# checking Images in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiwebview

i have a UIWebview where i am displaying text and images(data pulled from and xml feed)
the path for the images is comprised of an ID appended to a string and converted to a url, and then put as an  within the webview. however this means that there might not always be an image at the path so i put in

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imagePath];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
if(img == nil){
    imagePath = @"http://website.co.uk/filesout/pic.jpg";
}
```

to check if the image exists and if not use a placeholder image, the problem with this is its a little clunky and slow

are there any other more elegant ways of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by slow? Are the images loaded synchronically?

Comment: slow meaning, when you push from the previous view controller, into the webview, is becomes unresponsive while it tries to download the image

Comment: I see, I've added an example for a non blocking way.

Answer (score 0):

If the placeholder-pic is always the same, you should integrate it into your project and deliver it within the application. So it will not be downloaded everytime it is used, but loaded from your Main-Bundle. This should speed it up, at least for the placeholder-pics.

Comment: the placeholder image is fine beacuse the <img src> is asyncrhonous, its the downloading of the image that is slowing it

Comment: So just to understand you correctly.
What slows down your App is, that everytime you check if an image is there it is downloaded. Have you checked, if there is something like a timeout for "dataWithContentsOfURL:"?
An other approach could be to just insert the imagepath for the placeholder-pic as alternate img src to the xml file. Thus you need not to care about the image and just can wait for your webview document to load.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the placeholder images as default in your html. Render your html completely and show it. Load in the meantime your images. To set the images in the already rendered html you can inject javascript with **stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:** as soon as they are downloaded completely. You've got to set ids to the img tags to identify every image you want to exchange later on, an md5 hash of the image url for example. The code could look something like this:

**Objective-C - stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString**

```
- (void)imageLoadedSuccessfullyWithBundlePath:(NSString *)aBundlePath andId:(NSString *)anId
{
   [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('%@').src = '%@';", 
     anId, aBundlePath]];
}
```